# Module with exactly one maximal submodule not local

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory

Let a module $V$ be local if it has a maximal submodule containing all proper submodules of $V$, hence it must be unique. Now, I have to prove the converse is not true, i.e, I have to find a module $V$ with a unique maximal submodule but $V$ is not local.

At first, I have thought that I must look for some module of infinite length, in particular, some module which is not finitely generated since otherwise all proper submodules are contained in a maximal one. However, I have not worked too much with these kind of modules and I would appreciate any hint!

Comment: As you correctly said, such a module cannot be finitely generated.  As a hint to your question, I would suggest you to try to find first a module  with no maximal submodules. Such a module will not satisfy your hypothesis  of course but by taking the external direct sum with an appropiate module,  you will be able to get a module satisfying your hypothesis.

Comment: Great, thank you so much!